# "-+" operator c# MONO 2.10.12

Tags: c#, mono

I just found very strange thing in my code. By mistake I have put as an index something like this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;

Dictionary<int, SomeClass> dic = new Dictionary<int, SomeClass> ();

dic[a -+ b].Field = 0;
```

As you can see there is "-+" opperator that really works as "-".
Anyway the code was having good time, was compiling until I found it.

It is part of code in Unity3d for game that I am working on now.

The question is: is it normal? Or this is know bug in mono 2 and was fixed. I cannot find any info about it.

Comment: `a -+-+-+-+-+-+- b` is also valid. but there is no `+-` operator. thats just combination of +,-.

Comment: Just get the spacing right to see it is correct: `dic[a - +b].Field = 0;`  Vary it up with `dic[a - -b].Field`.  Stun your team members with the goes-to operator: `var huh = a --> b;`  The unary + operator could have been left out of the language and few programmers would have missed it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing strange about this, and there isn't a `-+` operator. There's a unary `+` operator and a binary `-` operator. Just add parentheses and some spacing to make it clearer:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = a -+ b;
int d = a - (+b); // Same as above
```

Note that you can use `+-` as well, with the unary `-` operator and the binary `+` operator:

```
int e = a +- b;
int f = a + (-b); // Same as above
```

And while you can't use `++` or `--` like this, because those really *are* separate operators, you can add a space:

```
int g = a + + b;
int h = a + (+b); // Same as above

int i = a - - b;
int j = a - (-b); // Same as above
```

You can also have multiple unary operators chained together, for real craziness:

```
int k = a +-+-+-+ b;
int l = a + (-(+(-(+(-(+b)))))); // Same as above
```

Comment: You should get a new badge for having the first rep that needs 2 lines